# save file from filechooser to my courent directory of project

Tags: java, user-interface, filechooser

i want to copy file that filechooser was selected , to my project directory 
is use this code for my file chooser ,

but i cant find any thing to help me to copy or load that file to my project and use to my ui, what am i doing?

its my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FileChooser extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    static private final String newline = "\n";
    JButton openButton, saveButton;
    JTextArea log;
    JFileChooser fc;

    public FileChooser() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        log = new JTextArea(5,20);
        log.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
        log.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

        fc = new JFileChooser();

        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        openButton = new JButton("Open a File...",
                createImageIcon("images/Open16.gif"));
        openButton.addActionListener(this);

        saveButton = new JButton("Save a File...",
                createImageIcon("images/Save16.gif"));

        saveButton.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); //use FlowLayout
        buttonPanel.add(openButton);
        openButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);
        saveButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        buttonPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255));
        add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    private File file;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean isOpen=false;
        //Handle open button action.
        if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooser.this);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                //This is where a real application would open the file.
                log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
                isOpen=true;
            } else {
                log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
            }
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());

            //Handle save button action.
        } else if (e.getSource() == saveButton && isOpen) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            File file=fc.getSelectedFile();
            new File(file.getName(),"./images/" );
            System.out.println("--"+file.getName());

            log.append("Saving: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
        }
    }
    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = FileChooser.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE); 
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FileChooserDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
        frame.add(new FileChooser());
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe JNDI could help lookup project folder

Comment: i read a little about it , thanks , i want to load or save ,..., and any way that help me to use that file( file that is selected)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
/**
* THE REST OF YOUR CODE
*/
java.nio.file.Files.copy( 
                   file.toPath(), 
                   new java.io.File(file.getName()).toPath(),
                   java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
                   java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES,
                   java.nio.file.LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS );
```

I assumed you wanted to make sure the File had the same name as before. Otherwise, replace file.getName() with what you want to name the file.

Comment: thanks for reply :) i use this code , but eclipe give me error "java.nio.Files" cannot be resolve as a type.and another error for 2 end line of above code."java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES.nio cannot be resolved or is not a 
 field" and syntax error :(

Comment: Ok, I've fixed the typos. Dropped a comma and a word from the initial input.

Comment: thanks a lot, but not work :( , is my work true? i copy this code and past it after of File file=fc.getSelectedFile(); code in public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  function, its true?